# How to fetch multiple selected record Id in conga composer from visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, conga, conga-composer

When i selected multple record and click on the Button then On redirect conga composer then showing this error like:Not authorized. 
The [a0q6C000005aoY3QAI, a0q6C000005aoXoQAI] parameter ID is not valid. Ensure that the parameter ID is 15 to 18 alpha-numeric characters and does not include spaces.
how to get the id in conga composer

///////////visualforce page

```
<apex:commandButton value=" Summary Invoice"   action="{!SummaryInvoice}"  oncomplete="opensummaryConga('{!selectedEsr}')"     style="background:#eed202;"/>
<Script Language="JavaScript"> 

var stringsummaryvalue='{!selectedEsr}';
var Formastring=stringsummaryvalue.splits(',');
var joinIds=Formastring.join("'|'");
var removeSpace=joinIds.replace(" ","");
var removeLeft=removeSpace.replace("[","");
var removeRight=removeLeft.replace("]","");
var finalSetIds=removeRight;
<!----var Formastring=stringsummaryvalue.splits(',');--->

             function opensummaryConga(finalSetIds) {
             <!--function openConga()--->

            <!-- GenerateInvoicePay();-->

                alert('summary Id2'+finalSetIds);  


                window.location.href = "/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1&"+
                                       "id="+finalSetIds+"&serverUrl={!$API.Partner_Server_URL_370}";


              }
```

---

////////controller///////

```
 public PageReference SummaryInvoice() 
            {
            selectedEsr = new List<Payment__c>();
               system.debug('paymentlist---==='+paymentList);

                  for(wrappayment wp : paymentList)
                { 
                Payment__c p=new Payment__c();
                if(wp.selected == true)
                { 
                p=wp.pay;



                    }
                    selectedEsr.add(p);

                }
                system.debug('selectedEsrline583---==='+selectedEsr); 
             return Null;
            }
```

Comment: I don't know enough about Conga, but I do know that `id` only accepts one ID value; you may need to use QVar0 or another parameter to load the records you'd like.

Comment: How to do use Qvar0 in visualforce page